# Vs code terminal wrong

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm having a problem with my vs code terminal whenever I run code. Look, here I was printing a number and it prints it like this:
[image]

It is the number inside the red circle, but it is surrounded by this information. I don't know what caused it, but it annoys me when I'm trying to test the code.

I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Could you please provide the code fragment which is printing this?

Comment: Yes, it is just:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ cout<<168070<<endl;
return 0;}

Comment: Looks like it 'echoes' the commands issued by VS Code to build and run your program to the same console stream. Could you please share what you have in `tasks.json`?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev this is what it shows.

Comment: Hmm, it looks good. And the output looks like the output from debugger. Try checking `launch.json` for the command used to start debugging. Maybe there is some parameter to separate the output streams from the application and from the debugger or VS Code itself.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).